# Factoring Literal Numbers Software

Tags: factoring, math-software

I need a math software that has scripting capability which can do something like this:

let $W=m\cdot N/s$

$factor(W, V=m\cdot N/s\cdot A)$

$V=W/A$

And suggestions?

Comment: if the periods mean multiplication `\cdot` is better. Also false unless parenthesized properly.

Comment: You may try Wolfram language `V == m N/(s A) /. m N/s -> W` which comes very close to what you want.

Comment: ill give that a try..